# Troubles with DNSCrypt and company LAN

Tags: networking, security, dns

I want to use DNSCrypt. But unfortunately, when using it, I have troubles accessing my company network.
I cannot access HDD on the NAS.
When deactivating DNSCrypt by removing 127.0.0.1 from DNS everything works.

Is there a way to use DNSCrypt and company Services without problems?
e.g.: deactivate DNSCrypt for LAN, but not internet?

Answer (score 1):

Manually add all you work resources to the [HOSTS file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) on your PC and leave DNSCyrpt enabled.

You HOSTS file will be checked before DNS lookups happen.

Comment: Thanks, I will try. Which way would the entries look like? 192.168.0.1 \\COMPANY_NAS for example?

Comment: Help, please? :(